# Is there a way to get my song on spotify for free?

Tags: instrumental, spotify

I Have Written a few Songs(most of them instrumental) & I was wondering if there was a way I could get them put on spotify for free.

Comment: Hi Paul, this question is off-topic here (see [this page](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). It is probably allowed on [Music Practice & Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/), but if you want to be sure you can first ask on their [Meta site](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because business questions are off-topic.

Comment: MP&T won't take it either - they don't allow business questions.

Comment: Darn it, None of the other stack exchange sites for music allow any business questions.